# stackpanel highlight on mouse over from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, stackpanel

From code behind I can set some generic things to my groupbox and stackpanel but I cant find anything on how to highlight a stack panel from code behind.

```
        GroupBox groupbox = new GroupBox(); 
        groupbox.Header = String.Format(node.Element("StudentID").Value); 
        groupbox.Width = 100; 
        groupbox.Height = 100; 
        groupbox.Margin = new Thickness(1); 

        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock(); 
        textBlock.Text = String.Format(node.Element("FirstName").Value + " " + (node.Element("LastName").Value)); 
        textBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center; 

        TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock(); 
        textBlock1.Text = (DateTime.Parse(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value)).ToString("d"); 
        String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", DateTime.Parse(node.Element("TimeAdded").Value)); 
        textBlock1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center; 
        textBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom; 

        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel(); 
        stackPanel.Children.Add(groupbox); 

        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock); 
        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock1); 
        stackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(5);
```

I wish to on mouse over create a highlight of a ligher grey, also this code belongs to a customcontrol.

Comment: Hook the mouse event and change the background color?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this in code-behind rather than in XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add handlers for the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StackPanel stackpanel = new StackPanel(); 
    stackpanel.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(stackpanel_MouseEnter);
    stackpanel.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(stackpanel_MouseLeave);
}

void stackpanel_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackpanel = (StackPanel)sender;
    stackpanel.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
}

void stackpanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackpanel = (StackPanel)sender;
    stackpanel.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
}
```